# Can I enable Bounce Keys for certain keys only?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 15.04

On  my laptop, I'm having  a persistent issue where keystrokes on the space bar are being  repeated. Having been through  a number  of  replacements, as well as trying multiple operating systems, I have judged that  the issue  is a hardware one, not a software one.

Fortunately, I learned that Ubuntu had a feature known as  bounce keys, which  would allow me to counteract the issue, as repeated keystrokes would be  filtered.

However, enabling the solution for all keys sometimes filters keys that I don't  want to be filtered. For instance, when I type *hello*, I often press the two *l*s in quick succession, however sometimes one of the *l*s is filtered, which can  be quite annoying. I know I'll never need to press the space bar  twice  in such quick succession, and since I'm only having problems with the space bar, I only want to enable  bounce keys on the space  bar.

So, is it possible to *only*  enable bounce  keys on the space bar?

Comment: Repeated how many times? Does it happen everytime?

Comment: It doesn't happen every time, but it's enough to be quite annoying. I'd say that it happens around three times a paragraph. It can be very irritating to have to go back and edit out the extraneous spaces.

Comment: The space is usually repeated about twice. If  you  see the source of my original post, you should easily be able to see the repeated spaces, as I've intentionally left them in.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but before reading it, read through [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11905883/).

Comment: Thanks, will try later - I've just been really busy, so haven't had a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xset - user preference utility for X

r is to control autorepeat.

> xset -r 10

will disable autorepeat for the "1" key.

> xset r 10

will enable autorepeat for the "1" key.

> xset r [keycode]

in my case keycode for space bar is 65 check for yours with 
code: `xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'`

Still if you need to change speed of keys you can also use rate parameter to it.

And also add this command to your session start script file.

Comment: You can get the current list of which keys have autorepeat enabled with `xset q`. It's a 256 bit array dumped in hex, and quite hard to read.

Comment: I'll definitely be sure to give this a go. Thanks!

Comment: Worked fine for me. Enjoy the +100 rep!

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution for you, but it doesn't involve Bounce Keys. What I do here is to deactivate the space key/keyboard for a small time each time space is pressed. So here it goes:

We use `xbindkeys` to capture space bar press (in this case release) and `xdotool` to insert spaces. Install them if you don't have it on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xdotool
```

A xbindkeys config file should have appeared on your home folder by the name `.xbindkeysrc` else create one like this:

```
xbindkeys -d > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Copy the snippet and paste it into your .xbindkeysrc file.

```
"xdotool key KP_Space; xinput set-int-prop <kbd-id> "Device Enabled" 8 0; sleep .05 ; xinput set-int-prop <kbd-id> "Device Enabled" 8 1"
     m:0x0 + c:65 + Release
    space
```

Here `<kbd-id>` is the keyboard ID which can be found out by `xinput` command. Now you want to configure xbindkeys to start each time you start your computer.

Open `/etc/rc.local` and add the line `xbindkeys` before `exit 0`.

You are done. Open a terminal and type `xbindkeys` to start it for now. See if it does the job. If it did not catch the double spaces or characters after spaces are missing, adjust the `delay` in our command in `~/.xbindkeysrc` accordingly and reboot.

References:

- [Xbindkeys - Arch Documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys)

Comment: I had a few issues with this answer.

The xinput command you linked *doesn't* disable the keyboard, it disables the touchscreen. I tried to adapt the command to disable the keyboard, but that didn't work  either. The correct command is: `xinput float 13 ; sleep .1 ; xinput reattach 13 3`, which *does* work.

However, the solution itself doesn't work. When I start xbindkeys with this command, the space bar no longer enters a space. It does disable the keyboard briefly, as it should, but no space character is entered. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I also just found a way to disable the space key only. It depends  on xmodmap:

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 65=NoSymbol' ; sleep .1; xmodmap -e 'keycode 65=KP_Space`

Comment: @FaizSaleem, I am sorry about the first issue, it was my mistake. I gave my keyboard id, which is 10. You can find yours by typing `xinput`. But we won't need that, you've found a way to disable space alone.

Comment: About the second issue, I also only tested only if keyboard is getting deactivated. I tried inserting a space manually using `xdotool getactivewindow key KP_Space`, but it does not work.

Comment: `xdotool key space` also doesn't work, and every other method I've tried to insert a space has failed.

Comment: @FaizSaleem same here. I asked it as a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649797/xdotool-doesnot-work-with-xbindkeys), but got no response.

Comment: Even with the update, I'm having the same issue. :/