# Xdotool does not work with xbindkeys

Tags: shortcut-keys, xdotool, xbindkeys

I want to use xdotool with xbindkeys but it does not work.

This is what I tried first:

```
"xdotool type a"
    m:0x1 + c:50
    Shift + Shift_L
```

this is not a duplicate as I have tried the solutions from other questions too:

```
"sleep 1 && xdotool type --delay 15 'a'"
    m:0x1 + c:50
    Shift + Shift_L
```

and

```
"xset r off; xdotool type --window 0 a; xset r on"
    m:0x1 + c:50
    Shift + Shift_L
```

I know that xbindkeys is working properly because I could execute `echo test > /home/dalton/key.txt` with it.

Comment: Have you tried `key` instead of `type`? If it doesn't work, could you try with `xte` too from `xautomation` package.

Comment: Another thing, are you sure it's a `xdotool` cmd problem not a shortcut one `Shift + Shift_L` ?!

Comment: @Sneetsher, Yes I am sure. I successfully executed `touch test.txt` with xbindkeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The default for `xbindkeys` is to catch `Press` event. It catches `Shift + Shift_L` then `xdotool` generate `a` key stroke. We get:

  ```
  Shift + Shift_L + a
  ```

  Similar to pressing: <kbd>Shift_R</kbd>+<kbd>Shift_L</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (in this order)
- These solutions worked for me:

  On Press event

  ```
  "xdotool keyup Shift_L keyup Shift_R key a keydown Shift_R"
      m:0x1 + c:50
      Shift + Shift_L
  ```

  On Release event

  ```
  "xdotool keyup Shift_R key a keydown Shift_R"
      Release + m:0x1 + c:50
      Release + Shift + Shift_L
  ```

  Also it is possible to use small pre-delay but that is not perfect method.

  **Reference:** [xbindkeys + xdotool timing problems](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=136265)

Comment: Don't you get looping when you do this? I had to deactivate the key with xmodmap before using xdotool. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202436/run-program-on-a-key-press-without-interupting-the-key-event).

Comment: @daltonfury42, no, because I didn't add a recursive `keydown Shift_L`

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647616/can-i-enable-bounce-keys-for-certain-keys-only/649531#649531) and then [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11905883/).

Comment: @daltonfury42, I was following that post. what I think is the best: disable space using xmodmap permanently, remove it from shortcut of xbindkeys leave only keycode, let xdotool send space. I didn't tried yet but will make a test.

Comment: Then how will you catch/filter the bounce? You should create a file or something.

Comment: @daltonfury42, my suggestion in prev. comment didn't work. your 1st sol from the paste works the 2nd i'm almost sure  is a loop. What I found is xbindkeys catch only symcode (keycode in  the configuration is mapped to its symcode). So my shortcut doesn't trigger when I disabled the key using xmodmap. your 1st sol used that to avoid loop and filter bounce for that sort delay. your 2nd sol make loop as it generated the same shortcut.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26029/discussion-between-daltonfury42-and-sneetsher).

Comment: YOU JUST SAVED ME LIKE THE FINISH HOUR OF STRUGGLE. So dumb xdotool key doesn't just work as the action, but if we add the release we can get that to work, I hadn't gotten that far in the docs, thank you so much ugh life saver you are the man. I can finally use this keyboard reasonably now. LIFE SAVER.